# Complex if-elif in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a complex if else statement in python. These statements should check two variables. The sample code:

```
    if value1 == 0.1 and value2 > 2.05:
       value1  = value1 + 0.1
       return value1  
    elif value1  == 0.2 and value2 > 1.85:
       value1  = value1  + 0.1
    elif value1  == 0.3 and value2 > 1.95:
       value1  = value1  + 0.1
    elif value1  == 0.4 and value2 > 2.05:
       value1  = value1  + 0.1
    ...
    if value1 == 0.1 and value2 < 1.75:
       return value1  
    elif value1  == 0.2 and value2 < 1.85:
       value1  = value1  - 0.1
    elif value1  == 0.3 and value2 < 1.95:
       value1  = value1  - 0.1
    elif value1  == 0.4 and value2 < 2.05:
       value1  = value1  - 0.1
    ....
```

In total I have an if or elif for every value1 from 0.1 - 1. Every time value2 is a different value. What I want to do is to check also if value2 is less than a value in order to decrease `value1 = value -1`. Which is the most clever way to do so, without adding many if -elif statements?

Comment: Thats hard to say without knowing what pattern that "different value" follows

Comment: try using a loop and increment the variables

Comment: Can you post the if-elif version? Then we can better help optimize it. It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: This won't work anyway because of the floating-point comparison.

Comment: You have to post the whole thing in order for anyone to come up with a solution

Comment: So, by deduction, the pattern is simply (value2-value1) > 1.65? (edit except for 1st line) also, what do you have against or in same if?

Comment: Maybe a silly idea, but...what about a state machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no pattern or it's so complex that it can't be easily constructed with a loop then I would do something like this:

```
eq_gt_pairs = ((0.1, 2.05), (0.2, 1.85), (0.3, 1.95), (0.4, 2.05)) # ...

eq_lt_pairs = ((0.1, 1.75), (0.2, 1.85), (0.3, 1.95), (0.4, 2.05)) # ...

for pair in eq_gt_pairs:
    if value1 == pair[0] and value2 > pair[1]:
        return value1 + 0.1

for pair in eq_lt_pairs:
    if value1 == pair[0] and value2 < pair[1]:
        return value1 - 0.1
```

Comment: Why don't you unpack the pairs? `for left, right in eq_gt_pairs: if value1 == left and value2 > right:`

Comment: @Bakuriu If it was my code and there were known proper names for these values then I might, but in this context `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` is more meaningful to me than `left` and `right`.

Comment: How about `if (value1, value2) in eq_gt_pairs: return value1 + 0.1` ?

Comment: @Skycc that won't work in this case because the second values are doing '>' or '<'